# Photoshop: how to change color of shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers

I have a layer filled with some color. I want to change this color without rasterizing.

[image: Image looks like this][image: Layer looks like this]

Comment: I've used Blending Options -> Color Overlay. Is it normal way to do color change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click that icon in the layers panel and the 'Color Picker' opens up. Choose your new color and hit ok.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'color overlays' but in the Layers panel make sure your layer is set to 'normal' blending mode.